# How to add a CSS class to a div but not to its children with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding and removing a CSS class with JavaScript through a on click event. This is the structure of my div i am using.  I have a few more divs like the one here. I am able to remove and add the class to my div, but I want to be able to add it only to the div and not to the child elements like the heading and paragraph.

```js
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");

heading.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    heading.forEach((e) => e.classList.remove('bg_yellow'));
    event.target.classList.add('bg_yellow');
  })
})
```

```css
.bg_yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="sf_day_card_heading">
  <h5>MON</h5>
  <p>January 9</p>
</div>

<div class="sf_day_card_heading">
  <h5>MON</h5>
  <p>January 9</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use semantic elements when possible. It will make your app smoother on all levels. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You _are_ only adding the class to the parent. Do you mean the _styles_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

```
event.currentTarget.classList.add('bg_yellow');
```

`target` element that triggered the event
`currentTarget` element that has the event listener

Answer (score 0):

```js
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");

heading.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    el.classList.toggle('bg_yellow');
  })
})
```

```css
.bg_yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="sf_day_card_heading">
  <h5>MON</h5>
  <p>January 9</p>
</div>

<div class="sf_day_card_heading">
  <h5>MON</h5>
  <p>January 9</p>
</div>
```